# How to print a decimal number without exponential form / scientific notation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, scientific-notation, python-decimal

To print a floating point number without exponential form, we can write like this:

```
print('%f' % (10**-8))
```

But this generally displays zeroes due to precision error. Instead, we can use `Decimal.decimal(float)` to print a floating point number precisely. But that prints the number in exponential format i.e. `10e-10`. And I cannot seem to combine them as I don't know how to format a `Decimal` like the way I used `'%f'` to format floats.

So my question is, how to get this thing done the way I want?

Note: The power -8 used here is just an example. The power could be variable. Also, I was wondering if I could print the differences of two numbers with high precision.

Answer (score 3):

```
from decimal import Decimal
print('%.8f' % Decimal(10**-8))
```

Outputs:

```
0.00000001
```

To specify decimal places dynamically you can use this:

```
from decimal import Decimal

power = 10
print('%.*f' % (power, Decimal(10**-power)))
```

Prints:

```
0.0000000001
```

Comment: You showed the solution for 10**-8 only. What if the number power is variable? What if it changes?

Comment: The following code generates error:
`>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> a = 10**-8
>>> print("%.*f" % Decimal(a))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: * wants int`

Comment: @MerajAlMaksudMasuk you need to specify two numbers in your format - number of decimal places and the number.

Comment: Much better to use `.format`-style formatting rather than `%`-based formatting. For `%`-based formatting, a `Decimal` instance is just converted to the nearest `float` first, potentially introducing a rounding error. For `.format`-style formatting, formatting is applied directly to the actual `Decimal` value without a `float` conversion. (Assuming Python >= 3.1.)